# What are the alternatives to wmctrl?

Tags: linux, x11

Do you know of any alternatives to wmctrl?  A program that lets you manipulate windows and window management from the command line.

One drawback with wmctrl is that whilst you can manipulate the current window, you cannot get wmctrl to list information about the current window (it ignores -r).

Answer (score 11):

To find the id of the currently active window, use:

```
xprop -root -f _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW 0x " \$0\\n" _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW | awk "{print \$2}"
```

Using this id, you can then get a lot of information about the currently active window:

```
xprop -id $(xprop -root -f _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW 0x " \$0\\n" _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW | awk "{print \$2}")
```

From there, you can `grep` what you need, or make it show just the desired field the same way I extracted `_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW` above. So, to find the PID of the currently active window, you would append `-f _NET_WM_PID 0c " \$0\\n" _NET_WM_PID` to the command above, making it:

```
xprop -id $(xprop -root -f _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW 0x " \$0\\n" _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW | awk "{print \$2}") -f _NET_WM_PID 0c " \$0\\n" _NET_WM_PID | awk "{print \$2}"
```

Note that `wmctrl` also accepts the same kind of id in combination with the `-i` flag.

Answer (score 9):

You can trick wmctrl into outputting the ID number of the active window by turning on verbose mode and telling it to move the active window with an invalid parameter:

```
wmctrl -v -r :ACTIVE: -e dummy
```

While this *does* exit with an error status, it also outputs the ID number of the active window:

```
envir_utf8: 1
Using window: 0x08400004
The -e option expects a list of comma separated integers: "gravity,X,Y,width,height"
```

Once you have the ID number of the active window, you can list all the windows and search for that ID number:

```
 wmctrl -l
```

It's awkward to get information about the active window with wmctrl, but it's possible.

Comment: `wmctrl -a :ACTIVE: -v` also works and has the slight advantage of giving you a meaningful exit code.

Answer (score 2):

[xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) is a reasonable alternative ([github project here](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool)), although unfortunately [the author doesn't seem to care about it much any more](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool/issues/19).

Comment: Yes I have found xdotool useful.  It can give me the current window id with `xdotool getwindowfocus`

Comment: xdotool seems to be active.  
The last release is from Oct 21, 2021.  
The last update was from 13 days ago.

Answer (score 1):

My experience with wmctrl version 1.07 under RH Linux 5.5 and 5.6 64-bits is that
wmctrl gets completely lost at times.  For instance, when looking for a firefox window
the following returns nothing:

```
% wmctrl -lpGx | grep -i 'Firefox'
```

My suspicion is that wmcntl cannot find firefox windows due to the nature of the window manager, in this case, metacity.  This manager seems to reparent windows and perhaps this causes wmctrl not to list firefox windows.  'xwininfo' does list the firefox windows.

If you have access to xdotool (my version is 2.20110530.1) then you can try:

```
% mywin=`xwininfo -root -tree | awk '/- Mozilla Firefox/ { printf $1; exit}'`
% xdotool windowactivate --sync $mywin mousemove --window $mywin 0 0
```

This makes firefox active, makes it the top window in the stack on your desktop, and puts the mouse over it (as is sometimes needed when a user's environment sets focus to a window under the mouse without requiring a click.)  If you don't want the mouse to move simply
remove 'mousemove --window $mywin 0 0' from the above.

Note: I had the same problem with finding Konqueror windows on the same Linux systems.

Comment: Your wmctrl problem could be this: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=426383

Answer (score 1):

window id

```
wmctrl -a :ACTIVE: -v 2>&1 | grep "Using window: " | awk "{print \$3}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check [xdo](https://github.com/baskerville/xdo) which can do a decent job with minimal ressources.